# Spring Batch: Kafka poll takes ages to retrieve the messages?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, apache-kafka, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch application to retrieve messages from Kafka using Consumer poll method.

I am running Kafka (kafka_2.13-2.8.1.tgz) on my local windows machine. I created a topic and posted ~200 messages before start running the Spring Batch Job.

When the Spring Batch Job is started, it takes at least 15-45 minutes before it could retrieve the messages from Kafka which is **impacting the overall execution time**

```
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version: 2.3.1
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId: 18a913733fb71c01
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka startTimeMs: 1633429089967
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test] Subscribed to topic(s): Student
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test] Cluster ID: H1Y6WXmSQO-VHVYW6WUoSw
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test] Discovered group coordinator DVYVDIO4v2273D.demo.com:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test] (Re-)joining group
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test] (Re-)joining group
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:48:15.136
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:48:20.138
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:48:25.138
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:48:30.139
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:48:35.140
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:48:40.142
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:48:45.143
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:48:50.144
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:48:55.146
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Completed 2021-10-05T15:49:00.161

StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:49:50.749
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:49:55.750
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:50:00.752
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:50:05.753
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:50:10.755
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:50:15.758
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:50:20.758
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:50:25.761
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:50:30.761
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:50:35.763
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Completed 2021-10-05T15:50:40.764

StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:50:41.004
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:50:46.005
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:50:51.006
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:50:56.007
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:51:01.008
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:51:06.009
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:51:11.012
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:51:16.013
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:51:21.014
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:51:26.015
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Completed 2021-10-05T15:51:31.018

StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:51:31.283
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:51:36.283
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:51:41.285
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:51:46.286
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:51:51.288
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:51:56.291
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:52:01.291
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:52:06.292
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:52:11.293
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:52:16.295
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Completed 2021-10-05T15:52:21.298

StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:52:21.549
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:52:26.549
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:52:31.549
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:52:36.550
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:52:41.551
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:52:46.553
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:52:51.554
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:52:56.556
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:53:01.558
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:53:06.559
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test] (Re-)joining group
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test] (Re-)joining group
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Completed 2021-10-05T15:53:11.561
 
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:53:11.812
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:53:16.814
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:53:21.816
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:53:26.817
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:53:31.819
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:53:36.820
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:53:41.821
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:53:46.824
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:53:51.825
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:53:56.825
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Completed 2021-10-05T15:54:01.826

StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:54:02.082
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:54:07.083
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:54:12.084
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:54:17.086
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:54:22.087
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:54:27.089
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:54:32.091
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:54:37.092
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:54:42.092
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:54:47.093
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Completed 2021-10-05T15:54:52.094

StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:54:52.374
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:54:57.375
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:55:02.375
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:55:07.375
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:55:12.377
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:55:17.378
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:55:22.380
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:55:27.382
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:55:32.384
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:55:37.386
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Completed 2021-10-05T15:55:42.388


StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:56:32.887
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:56:37.888
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:56:42.890
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test] Successfully joined group with generation 4
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test] Setting newly assigned partitions: Student-0
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test] Setting offset for partition Student-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=1336, offsetEpoch=Optional[0], currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=DVYVDIO4v2273D.demo.com:9092 (id: 0 rack: null), epoch=0}}
1
2

3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
Number of Records Consumed -->12
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:56:43.466
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:56:48.473
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:56:53.478
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:56:58.483
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:57:03.488
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:57:08.494
Number of Records Consumed -->0
StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:57:13.501
Number of Records Consumed -->0
Processing...1
Processing...2
Processing...
Processing...3
Processing...4
Processing...5
Processing...6
Processing...7
Processing...8
Processing...9
Processing...10
Processing...11
Hibernate: select next value for student_sequence
Hibernate: select next value for student_sequence
Hibernate: select next value for student_sequence
Hibernate: select next value for student_sequence
Hibernate: select next value for student_sequence
Hibernate: select next value for student_sequence
Hibernate: select next value for student_sequence
Hibernate: select next value for student_sequence
Hibernate: select next value for student_sequence
Hibernate: select next value for student_sequence
Hibernate: select next value for student_sequence
Hibernate: select next value for student_sequence
Hibernate: insert into STUDENTS (ENROLLED_DATE, STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into STUDENTS (ENROLLED_DATE, STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into STUDENTS (ENROLLED_DATE, STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into STUDENTS (ENROLLED_DATE, STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into STUDENTS (ENROLLED_DATE, STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into STUDENTS (ENROLLED_DATE, STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into STUDENTS (ENROLLED_DATE, STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into STUDENTS (ENROLLED_DATE, STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into STUDENTS (ENROLLED_DATE, STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into STUDENTS (ENROLLED_DATE, STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into STUDENTS (ENROLLED_DATE, STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into STUDENTS (ENROLLED_DATE, STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
StudentStg Processing Completed 2021-10-05T15:57:21.066

StudentStg Processing Started 2021-10-05T15:57:21.389
Number of Records Consumed -->0
```

**It started retrieving the messages only after Successfully joined in the group - why it it taking such a long time to (re)join in the group?**

> [main] INFO
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator -
> [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=test] Successfully joined group
> with generation 4

Below is my **Kafka Consumer Configuration class**

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() throws UnknownHostException {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProps());
    }

    /**
     * Create bean for ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory
     *
     * @return ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory
     * @throws UnknownHostException
     */
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory()
            throws UnknownHostException {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
        return factory;
    }

    /**
     * consumerProps
     *
     * @return consumerProperties
     * @throws UnknownHostException
     */
    public Map<String, Object> consumerProps() throws UnknownHostException {

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

        //local
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("group.id", "test");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
        props.put("max.poll.interval.ms", "70000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "100");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "900000");
        props.put("request.timeout.ms", "300000");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "600000");
        props.put("heartbeat.interval.ms", "1000");
        props.put("default.api.timeout.ms", "2147483647");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Below **kafka consumer configuration is applied**

```
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig - ConsumerConfig values:
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 1000
    auto.offset.reset = latest
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id =
    client.rack =
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 2147483647
    enable.auto.commit = true
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = test
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 1000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 900000
    max.poll.records = 100
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 300000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 600000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

Below is my **job-definition.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.*" />

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="irusDataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProperties"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.demo.*</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemWriter">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean> 

<!-- Simple step used as parent of all steps in item recode -->
<bean id="simpleStep" class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleStepFactoryBean"
      abstract="true">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="startLimit" value="10" />
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>

<batch:job id="readStudentFromKafka"  incrementer="incrementer">
    <batch:step id="kafkaSSReadSingleStep" parent="simpleStep">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <batch:chunk
                    reader="StudentStgReader"
                    processor="StudentStgProcessor"
                    writer="StudentStgWriter"
                    commit-interval="10">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="StudentStgReader" class="com.demo.batch.jobs.kafka.StudentStgReader" />

<bean id="StudentStgProcessor" class="com.demo.batch.jobs.kafka.StudentStgProcessor" />

<bean id="StudentStgWriter" class="com.demo.batch.jobs.kafka.StudentStgWriter">
    <constructor-arg ref="hibernateItemWriter"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jobExplorer"
      class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="demoDataSource"
      p:tablePrefix="BATCH_"/>
```

Below is my **Spring Batch Reader class**

```
public class StudentStgReader implements ItemReader<List<String>> {
    private static KafkaConsumer<Integer, String> consumer;
    public static final String TOPIC_NAME = "Student";
    private String storeFilter;
    private String divisionCode;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaConsumerConfig kafkaconfig;

    // Implementation for store specific read from Kafka
    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
        JobParameters parameters = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getJobParameters();
        storeFilter = parameters.getString("retailsStoreId");
        divisionCode = parameters.getString("divisionCode");
        System.out.println("Filtered Store Ids: " + parameters.getString("retailsStoreId") + "Filtered Division Code"
                + divisionCode);
    }

    public List<String> read() throws UnknownHostException, JAXBException {
        return readMessagesFromTopic();
    }

    private List<String> readMessagesFromTopic() throws UnknownHostException {
        List<String> records = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> recordsConsumed = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println(String.format("StudentStg Processing Started %s", new LocalDateTime()));
        try {
            Iterator<ConsumerRecord<Integer, String>> iterator = getKafkaConsumer().poll(Duration.ofMillis(5000))
                    .records(TOPIC_NAME).iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String xmlValue = iterator.next().value();
                System.out.println(xmlValue);

                recordsConsumed.add(xmlValue);
            }
            if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(recordsConsumed)) {
                records.addAll(recordsConsumed);
            }

            System.out.println("Number of Records Consumed -->" + recordsConsumed.size());

            consumer.commitAsync();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured " + e);
        } finally {
            consumer.commitSync();
        }
        return records;
    }

    private KafkaConsumer<Integer, String> getKafkaConsumer() throws UnknownHostException {
        //KafkaConsumerConfig kafkaconfig = new KafkaConsumerConfig();
        if (ObjectUtils.isEmpty(consumer)) {
            consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(kafkaconfig.consumerProps());
            consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton(TOPIC_NAME));
        }
        return consumer;
    }
}
```

Below is my **Spring Batch Processor class**

```
public class StudentStgProcessor implements ItemProcessor<List<String>, List<Student>> {

    @Override
    public List<Student> process(List<String> results) throws Exception {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String message : results) {
            System.out.println("Processing..." + message);
            //Thread.sleep(250);

            Student student = new Student();
            student.setStudentName(message);
            student.setEnrolledDate(new Date());

            students.add(student);
        }
        return students;
    }

}
```

Below is my **Spring Batch Writer class**

```
public class StudentStgWriter implements ItemWriter<List<Student>> {
    private HibernateItemWriter<Student> hibernateItemWriter;

    public StudentStgWriter(HibernateItemWriter<Student> hibernateItemWriter) {
        this.hibernateItemWriter = hibernateItemWriter;

        System.out.println("Hibernate Writer instance is created..: " + hibernateItemWriter.hashCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends List<Student>> items) throws Exception {
        try {
            for (List<Student> StudentStg : items) {
                hibernateItemWriter.write(StudentStg);
            }

            hibernateItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
            System.out.println(String.format("StudentStg Processing Completed %s", new LocalDateTime()));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error occured : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Why it is taking so time to retrieve the existing messages from Kafka? How do I enforce the application to retrieve data without having to wait?

**Updated the configuration:**

```
public Map<String, Object> consumerProps() throws UnknownHostException {

    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

    //local
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("group.id", "test");
    props.put("group.instance.id", "test-123456");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "100");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);

    //Delay between the pools
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "900000");

    //client is going to wait this much time for the server to respond to a request
    //props.put("request.timeout.ms", "300000");

    //timeout used to detect client failures when using Kafka's group management facility
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "150000");

    //frequency of sending heart beat signal by the consumer
    //props.put("heartbeat.interval.ms", "1000");

    //This configuration is used as the default timeout for all client operations that do not specify a timeout parameter
    props.put("default.api.timeout.ms", "300000");

    return props;
}
```

Comment: Why are your timeout and max poll intervals so large? Increasing those values won't help make anything run quicker... What if you just use the default client configs?

Comment: Also, you want to change `auto.offset.reset = latest` if you plan on consuming previously produced data... Also, are there other consumers with the same group id preventing your instance here from joining the group? Plus, code with localhost doesn't match the brokers listed in the logs

Comment: there is only one consumer at all times.

Comment: updated the code as you suggested - updated the question as well.

Comment: default client configs does not work for me, it throws timeout errors

Comment: I don't see how you'd get timeout errors on localhost. In any case, is there a specific reason you need to use spring-batch? Kafka Connect JDBC Sink is commonly used to write to databases

Comment: I don't think the issue is related to Spring Batch. The reader uses a KafkaConsumer behind the scene, so the issue should be related to the consumer properties.